# Add to Cart button not translating on submission

Tags: addtocart

The "Add to Cart" Button text is not translating correctly after the product has been added to the cart. Please see below for screenshots of the issue.

On product page load, the translation for the "**Add to Cart**" is working as expected and button is translated to "**Add to Basket**" as shown in the image below.

The Product goes through the process of being added to the cart as expected, but when the add to cart process is completed the "**Add to Cart**" button shows the default string rather than the translation as show in the image below.

How can i fix it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override `catalog-add-to-cart.js` file in your theme.

create `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Catalog/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js` file.

Find:

```
var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('Add to Cart');
```

Replace it to:

```
var addToCartButtonTextDefault = self.options.addToCartButtonTextDefault || $t('Add to Basket');
```

Answer (score 2):

1.You need to rename "Add to Cart" button to "Add to Basket".
To do this follow below path.

> app/i18n/[custom]/en_US/en_US.csv

add below the words in csv.

```
"Add to Cart","Add to Basket"
```

It will change every where text of "Add to Cart" button is visible.

Comment: i tried but not wokring. it will "Add to Basket" > "Add.." > back to "Add to Cart" @PareshaU

Comment: you can also put it in your custom theme. app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[theme]/i18n/en_US.csv. after do the changes please run commands:bin/magento setup:upgrade,bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy,bin/magento cache:flush